# Global objects in C++ says duplicate symbols

Tags: c++, class, g++, global-variables

I am a beginner C++ programmer. So this might sound as a very simple question. But still I am confused.

I've always been wondering why does a class in C++ end with a semicolon, (`;`) like `union` and `struct`. So I created this class file.

```
// Test.h
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test {

    public:
        Test();
        ~Test();
        void setName(string);
        string getName();

    private:
        string name;
} test1, test2;  // This is what I called a `global object`

#endif
```

Now I created an implementation for this:

```
// Test.cpp
#include "Test.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


Test::Test() {

    cout << "Object created" << endl;
}

Test::~Test() {

    cout << "Object destroyed" << endl;
}

void Test::setName(string name) {

    this->name = name;
}

string Test::getName() {

    return name;
}
```

`Test.cpp` compiles successfully. I compiled it using `g++` compiler like this:

```
g++ -c Test.cpp
```

This produced `Test.o` file.

Now in my `Main.cpp`, this is what I have:

```
// Main.cpp
#include "Test.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;    

int main() {

    /* I did not declare test1 and test2 in main as they are already global. */

    test1.setName("Smith");
    test2.setName("Jones");

    cout << test1.getName() << endl;
    cout << test2.getName() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The **PROBLEM** arises while compiling `Main.cpp`:

When I compile it like this:

```
g++ Main.cpp Test.o -o Test
```

It gives me the following error:

```
duplicate symbol _test1 in:
/var/folders/4q/9x9vs76s6hq2fpv11zwtxmvm0000gn/T/Main-a59cee.o
Test.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

So how should I get this working? any help?
Thanks in  advance :)

**PS**: I am on a macbook pro 64-bit.

Comment: And a suggestion as you said you are a beginner in C++. Avoid `using namespace` statement especially in header files. When we are implementing a namespace in a cpp file, we can state `using namespace`.

Comment: } test1, test2 ... allowed but unusual and is causing your issue. Separate declaration from definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need to declare global objects in header, then try this:

```
// Test.h
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test {

    public:
        Test();
        ~Test();
        void setName(string);
        string getName();

    private:
        string name;
};
extern Test test1, test2;  // This is what I called a `global object`

#endif
```

Now in the implementation file (Test.cpp), define them:

```
// Test.cpp
    Test test1, test2; 
// continue your implementation of the class Test as earlier
```

Answer (score 2):

By defining variables in a header, and including that header from multiple files, you're defining them more than once. That's an error: the One Definition Rule says that global variables may only be defined once within a program.

To fix it, move the variable definitions into a source file; `Test.cpp` would be appropriate here; and declare them `extern` in the header so they're available from other source files.

```
// Test.h
extern Test test1, test2;  

// or combine with the class definition if you really want
extern class Test {
    // ...
} test1, test2;

// Test.cpp
Test test1, test2;
```